# How Do I Get USB Tethering Working Between 15.10 and an Android Device?

Tags: android, 15.10, tethering

Environment: Ubuntu 15.10 on a Dell L502X

I used to be able to use USB tethering between Ubuntu and an Android device without problems. Late last year, I applied a fresh install of Ubuntu (15.10) on the notebook. Now, with this combination, I cannot get USB tethering to work. I have tried a Nexus 4 (running Android 5.1, which used to work with the Ubuntu 15.04 that I used previously), a Nexus 5 (running Android 6.0.1), and a Nexus 5X (running Android 6.0.1).

When I enable USB tethering, I get a new entry in `ifconfig` output:

```
enx92c991095e89 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 92:c9:91:09:5e:89  
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:7 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:520 (520.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Note that the hardware address changes with each tether, so turning USB tethering off, then back on, or switching to a different Nexus device, gives me a replacement entry:

```
enx82fb7388a85c Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 82:fb:73:88:a8:5c  
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:332 (332.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

I also get a corresponding Wired entry in the Network screen in System Settings, showing the hardware address matching the `ifconfig` stanza, and described as either "Disconnected" (for the current enabled USB tethering session) or "Unmanaged" (for a prior USB tethering session).

Having GUFW enabled or disabled has no impact on the problem. Connecting directly or through a USB hub has no impact on the problem.

My `/etc/network/interfaces` is standard:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Is there anything else that I need to do on Ubuntu 15.10 to get Android USB tethering to work?

**UPDATE**: Here are the logs requested by @bain:

```
Jan 16 08:22:09 L502X kernel: [ 5377.812495] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
Jan 16 08:22:09 L502X kernel: [ 5377.945753] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=18d1, idProduct=4ee2
Jan 16 08:22:09 L502X kernel: [ 5377.945763] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Jan 16 08:22:09 L502X kernel: [ 5377.945768] usb 1-1: Product: Nexus 5X
Jan 16 08:22:09 L502X kernel: [ 5377.945772] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: LGE
Jan 16 08:22:09 L502X kernel: [ 5377.945776] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 00f204f982a4b8b9
Jan 16 08:22:10 L502X org.gtk.Private.GPhoto2VolumeMonitor[1780]: (process:2108): GVFS-GPhoto2-WARNING **: device (null) has no BUSNUM property, ignoring
Jan 16 08:22:10 L502X kernel: [ 5378.080031] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp6s0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:16fe:b5ff:febb:2732 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8612 LEN=24 
Jan 16 08:22:10 L502X kernel: [ 5378.080049] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp6s0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:16fe:b5ff:febb:2732 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8610 LEN=24 
Jan 16 08:22:10 L502X kernel: [ 5378.090303] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp6s0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:16fe:b5ff:febb:2732 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8612 LEN=24 
Jan 16 08:22:10 L502X kernel: [ 5378.090319] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp6s0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:16fe:b5ff:febb:2732 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8610 LEN=24 
Jan 16 08:22:11 L502X org.gtk.Private.GPhoto2VolumeMonitor[1780]: (process:2108): GVFS-GPhoto2-WARNING **: device (null) has no BUSNUM property, ignoring
Jan 16 08:22:11 L502X colord[1165]: (colord:1165): Cd-WARNING **: CdMain: failed to emit DeviceAdded: failed to register object: An object is already exported for the interface org.freedesktop.ColorManager.Device at /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/sysfs__null_
Jan 16 08:22:14 L502X colord-sane: io/hpmud/musb.c 2081: Invalid usb_open: Permission denied
Jan 16 08:22:30 L502X kernel: [ 5398.876832] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 3
Jan 16 08:22:31 L502X kernel: [ 5399.213700] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
Jan 16 08:22:31 L502X kernel: [ 5399.346845] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=18d1, idProduct=4ee4
Jan 16 08:22:31 L502X kernel: [ 5399.346855] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Jan 16 08:22:31 L502X kernel: [ 5399.346860] usb 1-1: Product: Nexus 5X
Jan 16 08:22:31 L502X kernel: [ 5399.346864] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: LGE
Jan 16 08:22:31 L502X kernel: [ 5399.346868] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 00f204f982a4b8b9
Jan 16 08:22:31 L502X mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 4: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:04:00.0/usb1/1-1"
Jan 16 08:22:31 L502X mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 4 was not an MTP device
Jan 16 08:22:31 L502X kernel: [ 5399.385223] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ether
Jan 16 08:22:31 L502X kernel: [ 5399.392871] rndis_host 1-1:1.0 usb0: register 'rndis_host' at usb-0000:04:00.0-1, RNDIS device, 9a:ff:bd:ee:76:ea
Jan 16 08:22:31 L502X kernel: [ 5399.392918] usbcore: registered new interface driver rndis_host
Jan 16 08:22:31 L502X NetworkManager[1070]: <warn>  (usb0): failed to find device 4 'usb0' with udev
Jan 16 08:22:31 L502X NetworkManager[1070]: <info>  (usb0): new Ethernet device (carrier: OFF, driver: 'rndis_host', ifindex: 4)
Jan 16 08:22:31 L502X kernel: [ 5399.398467] rndis_host 1-1:1.0 enx9affbdee76ea: renamed from usb0
Jan 16 08:22:31 L502X NetworkManager[1070]: <info>  (usb0): interface index 4 renamed iface from 'usb0' to 'enx9affbdee76ea'
Jan 16 08:22:31 L502X NetworkManager[1070]: <info>  devices added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:04:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/net/enx9affbdee76ea, iface: enx9affbdee76ea)
Jan 16 08:22:31 L502X NetworkManager[1070]: <info>  device added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:04:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/net/enx9affbdee76ea, iface: enx9affbdee76ea): no ifupdown configuration found.
Jan 16 08:22:31 L502X NetworkManager[1070]: <info>  (enx9affbdee76ea): device state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed') [10 20 2]
Jan 16 08:22:31 L502X kernel: [ 5399.442941] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enx9affbdee76ea: link is not ready
Jan 16 08:22:31 L502X NetworkManager[1070]: <info>  (enx9affbdee76ea): link connected
Jan 16 08:22:31 L502X NetworkManager[1070]: <info>  (enx9affbdee76ea): device state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none') [20 30 0]
Jan 16 08:22:31 L502X NetworkManager[1070]: <info>  Device 'enx9affbdee76ea' has no connection; scheduling activate_check in 0 seconds.
Jan 16 08:22:31 L502X kernel: [ 5399.458876] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp6s0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:16fe:b5ff:febb:2732 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8612 LEN=24 
Jan 16 08:22:31 L502X kernel: [ 5399.458904] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp6s0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:16fe:b5ff:febb:2732 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8610 LEN=24 
Jan 16 08:22:31 L502X kernel: [ 5399.469062] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp6s0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:16fe:b5ff:febb:2732 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8612 LEN=24 
Jan 16 08:22:31 L502X kernel: [ 5399.469088] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp6s0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:16fe:b5ff:febb:2732 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8610 LEN=24 
Jan 16 08:22:33 L502X ModemManager[1081]: <info>  Couldn't find support for device at '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:04:00.0/usb1/1-1': not supported by any plugin
Jan 16 08:22:35 L502X colord-sane: io/hpmud/musb.c 2081: Invalid usb_open: Permission denied
```

**UPDATE #2**: Fresh syslog, after disabling the firewall via GUFW:

```
Jan 16 09:33:23 L502X kernel: [ 9649.766835] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
Jan 16 09:33:23 L502X kernel: [ 9649.900519] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=18d1, idProduct=4ee2
Jan 16 09:33:23 L502X kernel: [ 9649.900529] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Jan 16 09:33:23 L502X kernel: [ 9649.900534] usb 1-1: Product: Nexus 5X
Jan 16 09:33:23 L502X kernel: [ 9649.900538] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: LGE
Jan 16 09:33:23 L502X kernel: [ 9649.900542] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 00f204f982a4b8b9
Jan 16 09:33:23 L502X org.gtk.Private.GPhoto2VolumeMonitor[1780]: (process:2108): GVFS-GPhoto2-WARNING **: device (null) has no BUSNUM property, ignoring
Jan 16 09:33:24 L502X org.gtk.Private.GPhoto2VolumeMonitor[1780]: (process:2108): GVFS-GPhoto2-WARNING **: device (null) has no BUSNUM property, ignoring
Jan 16 09:33:24 L502X colord[1165]: (colord:1165): Cd-WARNING **: CdMain: failed to emit DeviceAdded: failed to register object: An object is already exported for the interface org.freedesktop.ColorManager.Device at /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/sysfs__null_
Jan 16 09:33:26 L502X kernel: [ 9652.898664] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 6
Jan 16 09:33:26 L502X kernel: [ 9653.233755] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
Jan 16 09:33:26 L502X kernel: [ 9653.367239] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=18d1, idProduct=4ee4
Jan 16 09:33:26 L502X kernel: [ 9653.367249] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Jan 16 09:33:26 L502X kernel: [ 9653.367254] usb 1-1: Product: Nexus 5X
Jan 16 09:33:26 L502X kernel: [ 9653.367258] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: LGE
Jan 16 09:33:26 L502X kernel: [ 9653.367262] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 00f204f982a4b8b9
Jan 16 09:33:26 L502X kernel: [ 9653.375259] rndis_host 1-1:1.0 usb0: register 'rndis_host' at usb-0000:04:00.0-1, RNDIS device, 4e:8a:8f:3f:b7:cb
Jan 16 09:33:26 L502X NetworkManager[1070]: <warn>  (usb0): failed to find device 5 'usb0' with udev
Jan 16 09:33:26 L502X NetworkManager[1070]: <info>  (usb0): new Ethernet device (carrier: OFF, driver: 'rndis_host', ifindex: 5)
Jan 16 09:33:26 L502X mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 7: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:04:00.0/usb1/1-1"
Jan 16 09:33:26 L502X mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 7 was not an MTP device
Jan 16 09:33:26 L502X kernel: [ 9653.420245] rndis_host 1-1:1.0 enx4e8a8f3fb7cb: renamed from usb0
Jan 16 09:33:26 L502X NetworkManager[1070]: <info>  (usb0): interface index 5 renamed iface from 'usb0' to 'enx4e8a8f3fb7cb'
Jan 16 09:33:26 L502X NetworkManager[1070]: <info>  devices added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:04:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/net/enx4e8a8f3fb7cb, iface: enx4e8a8f3fb7cb)
Jan 16 09:33:26 L502X NetworkManager[1070]: <info>  device added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:04:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/net/enx4e8a8f3fb7cb, iface: enx4e8a8f3fb7cb): no ifupdown configuration found.
Jan 16 09:33:26 L502X NetworkManager[1070]: <info>  (enx4e8a8f3fb7cb): device state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed') [10 20 2]
Jan 16 09:33:26 L502X NetworkManager[1070]: <info>  (enx4e8a8f3fb7cb): link connected
Jan 16 09:33:26 L502X kernel: [ 9653.447746] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enx4e8a8f3fb7cb: link is not ready
Jan 16 09:33:26 L502X NetworkManager[1070]: <info>  (enx4e8a8f3fb7cb): device state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none') [20 30 0]
Jan 16 09:33:26 L502X NetworkManager[1070]: <info>  Device 'enx4e8a8f3fb7cb' has no connection; scheduling activate_check in 0 seconds.
Jan 16 09:33:27 L502X colord-sane: io/hpmud/musb.c 2081: Invalid usb_open: Permission denied
Jan 16 09:33:28 L502X ModemManager[1081]: <info>  Couldn't find support for device at '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:04:00.0/usb1/1-1': not supported by any plugin
```

**UPDATE #3**: `route -n` with USB tethering enabled, after `sudo dhclient ...`:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enx16d44e6a2773
192.168.42.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enx16d44e6a2773
```

Comment: Network device is up and received some packets. Is there anything relevant in NetworkManager logs or syslog? Suggest downloading 15.04 iso, boot and verify tether works (you don't need to install, just test the desktop), then try same again with 15.10 iso. Compare the logs. You might have hit a bug.

Comment: @bain: I added `/var/log/syslog` output to the question. The point when I toggled on USB tethering seems to be at the 08:22:31 mark. Where does NetworkManager have logs? I won't be in position to try your 15.04 ISO test for quite some time, unfortunately.

Comment: syslog is fine but I don't see any obvious errors. You could try shutting down NetworkManager then add the device to `/etc/network/interfaces` and `ifup` it. That should verify that the device is functional at least.

Comment: *[UFW BLOCK]* - maybe you have ufw installed and are blocking packets from the phone? Try `sudo ufw disable` and plug the phone in again.

Comment: @bain: "maybe you have ufw installed and are blocking packets from the phone?" -- I did for that first syslog, my apologies. An updated syslog is in the question. "You could try shutting down NetworkManager then add the device to /etc/network/interfaces and ifup it" -- that's beyond what I am in position to test right now, sorry.

Comment: Try `dhclient enx9affbdee76ea` (or whatever the device is appearing as)

Comment: @bain: OK, `sudo dhclient ...` gave me an IP address through tethering, and `ifconfig` shows traffic passing. However, `ping` and `traceroute` give me "Network is unreachable", for any IP address that I try, and Web browsers can't connect. Network Manager shows the connection as "Manual" (not DHCP) and has a gateway of `0.0.0.0` in the "IPv4 Settings"

Comment: Is a default route set (`route -n`)? Can you ping the gateway IP?

Comment: @bain: I added the `route -n` output above. The gateway IP is `0.0.0.0`; attempts to ping it work but actually ping `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Default route is missing. Two ideas. 1. `systemctl stop NetworkManager; dhclient -d enx.. ` look for `DHCPACK from 1.2.3.4` for IP  2. cat /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.leases` - check for line `option routers IP`. Then add default route with `route add default gw $IP` I suspect for Android it might be `route add default gw 192.168.42.129`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, thanks bain for the start of the answer, you almost solved it :)

Doing exactly what you said, you still cannot surf nor do things like `ping google.com`, annoying.

BUT, everything looked ok (route, ifconfig, /etc/resolv.conf pointing to 127.0.1.1...). Just to be sure, I tried to ping a known ip from google (206.169.145.232), and it worked !
Damn it, I do not know why the DNS are b0rked too, but you can use the temporary workaround by editing /etc/resolv.conf, and replacing 127.0.1.1 by 8.8.8.8 (and even add a second line `nameserver 8.8.4.4`).

You are set and can surf the web again !

Now, it would be great if somebody could figure out why kubuntu 15.10 (which is also affected by this bug) cannot do that automatically, like before.

Enjoy.

Comment: Just had the same issue on a Dell Inspiron 15 with Kubuntu 15.10. For whatever reason I had to open the network connection editor and add a new wired connection. Everything worked after that.

Answer (score 0):

What has happened is that your USB0 interfaces have been renamed to enx4e8a8f3fb7cb by the rndis_host driver. Simply edit your /etc/network/interfaces file and replace the USB0 interface with the renamed interface that rdis_host driver renamed.

To find this out after you plug your phone in and activate the tethering feature, run "ifconfig -a" in a terminal and you will see the new randomly generated interface, again you will not see USB0 anymore as it has been renamed by the rndis_host driver.

Answer (score -1):

The problem not on Ubuntu, I faced same issue on Windows 7

By somehow PC can't recognize Android network with DNS, to resolve this issue, are you using any blocking connection app on your android?

If yes disable it then try use USB tethering, if same problem do the following:

1. Install (Set DNS or DNS Changer) from Google play
2. Set Google DNS

   DNS1: 8.8.8.8

   DNS2: 8.8.4.4

Then press connect, after that try enable USB tethering.

It should work

Comment: Why would it be the Android device when the Android device provided Internet just fine with a previous version of Ubuntu?

Comment: I faced same problem on Windows 7 and I solved with same way.